# Environmental variable is empty into shell script but not in shell

Tags: android, bash, shell, sh, libvlc

A shell script checks some of my environmental variables, but this code:

```
if [ -z "$ANDROID_NDK" -o -z "$ANDROID_SDK" ]; then
    echo "You must define ANDROID_NDK, ANDROID_SDK before starting."
    echo "They must point to your NDK and SDK directories.\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

prints out `You must define ANDROID_NDK, ANDROID_SDK before starting. .....`, rather if in a shell I write the command `echo $ANDROID_SDK` or `echo $ANDROID_NDK` it gives me the right result.

Comment: Have you exported them from your shell, or only set them as variables?

Comment: the `env` command will show what variables you have defined in the environment.

Comment: Sorry but there is no need to downvote for nothing. btw i exported the variables inside my .bash_profile file and then i called `source .bash_profile`

Comment: I didn't downvote, I guess you should add the `env` output so we can see what is set? Also I assume a typo in the question? One of the `echo`s should be for the NDK?

Comment: Yes you write, i am going to edit my answer. in the end i find out the problem, see my answer.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder in my previous comment i misspelled a lot of words, i meant you were right about NDK and SDK in my question, see my answer for further informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question.
What i was trying was to compile libvlc using osx instead of Linux.
The problem was i don't know why but `unzip` was unable to extract the gradle.2.2.1.zip file so i thought i could do it using `sudo` but i was wrong because the execution of `compile.sh` was stopped in the code shown above because the enviromental variables are different for normal users and sudo.
In the end i solved my problem extracting the gradle zip file by hand and executing this commands by myself instead of let the shell script execute them:

```
cd gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}

./bin/gradle wrapper
checkfail "gradle: wrapper failed"

./gradlew -version
checkfail "gradle: wrapper failed"
cd ..
mkdir -p gradle
mv gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}/gradle/wrapper/ gradle
mv gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}/gradlew .
chmod +x gradlew
rm -rf gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-all.zip gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}
```

Basically this script should work well on Linux but it is obvious that unzip has some problems with it on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, I think, that wget failed due to a bad configuration but created the empty zip file. Then when relaunching script with wget working, it created .1 without warning.

Verify wget is working, delete every gradle-* file in the folder and relaunch compile.sh.

Comment: But thanks for the part concerning sudo and env, I did not know and was stuck due to the same issue.